# File extensions in asp.net and their definitions

Tags: asp.net

Any one please give me File extensions (like aspx, ascx etc) in asp.net and there definitions and were they use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Too lazy to dig in MSDN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete list can be found on MSDN:

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wawkw1c(v=vs.100).aspx**

For the ones you mentioned:

**aspx**

> An ASP.NET Web forms file (page) that can contain Web controls and
>   presentation and business logic. For more information, see Creating
>   ASP.NET Web Pages and ASP.NET Web Server Controls Overview.

**ascx**

> A Web user control file that defines a custom, reusable control. For
>   more information, see ASP.NET User Controls.

Comment: As mr.Curt said it nice link 

**A complete list can be found on MSDN:**

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wawkw1c(v=vs.100).aspx**


and also i fonde in some site there usage and functionality. they have give simple definetins and ther uses for just understading them. 

Here they are i seend just type the extion and seach them 
**http://www.file-extensions.org/
http://www.fileinfo.com/**

For expand ur knowledge its the best one as metion mr.Curt.

once agin thank you mr mr.Curt for giving your post to snall quation like this.